# How do I add lines to my php.ini using Salt Provisioner on a vagrant machine?

Tags: php, vagrant

I am new to using Vagrant, and am trying to set up salt provisioners.

Many times, when I find instructions on installing certain extensions etc, the instructions require that I modify the php.ini file.  How can I instruct SALT to modify the php.ini, for example, add a line to it etc?

Is this possible?

Comment: IMHO off topic, that one is related to serverfault or superuser.

Comment: I don't agree as  vagrant and salt become a very common way to set up developments envirounments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @pduersteler. Nevertheless

```
/path/to/php.ini:
  file.append:
    - text:
      - some configuration, that needs to be added
```

As per [docs](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html).